# send data to ajax from node server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json, ajax

i need to check if a token entred by user exist ,

**my node js controller :**

```
const checktoken = async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.body.token

    User.findOne({'token': token }).then((user) => {
        if (user) {
            return res.end("GOOOOD");
        }
        return res.end("Baad");
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))   
}
```

**Ajax side :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function (e) {
        // e.preventDefault()

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/token/'
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert(data)
        })
        .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("Errrrrrr       " + error);
        })
        .always(function(data){
        });
    })
})
```

**html form  :**

```
<form class="form-inline search-form"  action ="/api/token" method="POST" id="form">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <input name ="token" id="token" >
    </div>

    <button id="subBut" type ="submit"> Verify  </button>
</form>
```

the problem is i got always an alert (BAD token) whenever is good or not and then another page is printed with good result in text format

exemple if i put good token : Alert is Bad token then another page printed : good token (this means result from node is ok) the problem with AJAX

Comment: What's in `req.body`?  I don't see anywhere that you're sending the token.  Also, are you using bodyparser?

Comment: Assuming you are using express, the docs say `If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as res.send() and res.json().`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are double submitting because your `form` will submit while your `ajax` call will also fire. Change the action on the `form` to ensure that it won't try to post on its own (alternatively, you can uncomment `e.preventDefault` in your submit handler). Also, you aren't including any data in your ajax call:

```
<form class="form-inline search-form" action ="javascript:void(0)" id="form">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <input name ="token" id="token" >
    </div>

   <button id="subBut" type ="submit"> Verify  </button>
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function (e) {
    // e.preventDefault()

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '/api/token/',
            data: JSON.stringify({ token: $('#token').val() })
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert(data)
        })
        .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("Errrrrrr       " + error);
        })
        .always(function(data){
        });
    })
})
```

You haven't included your Express setup code, but this will require the line `app.use(Express.json())` or (`express.json()` depending on what you named the import) in order to parse the body from JSON into an object